# How do I make a command in discord.py that sends a dm to a user that i put thei user id?

Tags: discord, discord.py

How do I make a command in discord.py that sends a dm to a user that i put their user id?

Please help!!!

So I need to make a command that sends a DM to a user. Like this:
cb!dm-user

Can anyone help me with any full code and an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off make your command

```py
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx):
    '''DMs a user'''
```

Next you'll want to add an argument so you can choose who is DM'd. To do this we can make a variable defined as an argument.

```py
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, member : discord.Member = None):
    '''DMs a user'''
```

When running your command you will do `[p]dm @user`, python will take the @user argument and change `discord.Member = None` to `discord.Member = @userID`. Now you can use member as a variable. `discord.Member` is set to None so we don't get any errors.

Next you'll want to add the argument that chooses the text the person is DM'd with. We can do this by using a string (str) argument.

```py
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, member : discord.Member  =None, * , text : str = ""):
    '''DMs a user'''
```

`text` is now a variable in your code.
To get the bot to dm the user with the text we can add this line of code:

```py
await member.send(f"{text}")
```

Sorry if I explained poorly or used incorrect terms.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I understood very well!